# ampscript lookup to limit number of rows to display if there are more than 5 records

Tags: ampscript, dataextensions, marketing-cloud

hello currently working on an email that has table and the records are coming from another DE so im using LookupRows using contactId, I want to limit the number of records to be displayed to 5 however when i manually hardcode
for @i = 1 to 5
Im getting an error because of those records who have lesser rows

ie

ContactId - Orders (no of rows)

I hope someone would guide me, Thank you

```
%%[ 
set @rows = LookupRows("Data extension name","ContactId", @contactId)
 
for @i = 1 5 do 

set @row = Row(@rows, @i) 

set @orderNumber = Field(@row, "Order Number") 
set @orderDate= Field(@row, "Order Date") ]%% 

   <tr>

   <td%%=v(@orderNumber)=%%</td>

<td%%=v(@orderDate)=%%</td>

</tr>

%%[next @i]%%
```

Comment: please share your code / what you've tried so far so that we can help you.

Comment: hi @JonasLamberty thanks ill add my sample of code i tried above

Comment: you can check this one for the valid syntax:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321352/for-loop-causing-500-error-in-ampscript

Comment: Thank you, LookupOrderedRows helped!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop causing 500 error in AmpScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321352/for-loop-causing-500-error-in-ampscript)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to check the rowCount of your lookup first.

If there are less than 5 rows it won't compile.

```ampscript
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>Order Number</th>
 <th>Order Date</th> 
</tr>

%%[ 

set @contactID = "123"
set @rows = LookupRows("iowPB5mD","ContactID", @contactID)
set @rowCount = rowCount(@rows)
set @rowCount = iif(@rowCount > 5, 5, @rowCount)
output(concat("<br>ContactID: ", @contactID))
output(concat("<br>rowCount: ", @rowCount))

]%%

%%[ for @i = 1 to @rowCount do ]%%

      %%[
         set @row = Row(@rows, @i) 
         set @orderNumber = Field(@row, "Order Number") 
         set @orderDate= Field(@row, "Order Date") 
      ]%% 

         <tr>
         <td>%%=v(@orderNumber)=%%</td>
         <td>%%=v(@orderDate)=%%</td>
         </tr>

%%[ next @i ]%%

</table>
```

Output:

[image: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/kkvA4v3k]

You can test my code here: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/kkvA4v3k